# How to change the name of media device from terminal

Tags: command-line

I was trying to change the name of my portable HDD from terminal. usually the `rename` command is used or sometimes `mv`.

I am getting this error.

```
/media/dishank$ rename virus\ BOX/ virus_box virus\ BOX/
Search pattern not terminated at (eval 1) line 1.
```

Comment: What is the name of your device here `virus\ BOX/ virus_box virus\ BOX/` and what is the new name there?

Comment: Name of my media device is `virus BOX/`. And i want to change it to `virus_box/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I followed following steps:

1. Need to find the path of media device. mine was `/dev/sdc1` (use Gparted to find)
2. unmount the partition (do not disconnect it physically). ex: `sudo umount /dev/sdc1`
3. mine is ntfs so. `sudo ntfslabel /dev/sdc1 virus_box` and mount back your device.
4. verify changes through `sudo blkid`

All is done.

For more info [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RenameUSBDrive)

Answer (score 2):

`man -k label | grep -E 'file|volume'`

should print the names of a few relevant shell commands.
Check out the man pages.
You will probably need to prepended with `sudo` as you attempt to run any of them.

NOTE:
rename - renames multiple files
rm - remove files or directories
mv - move files

Comment: I did used `sudo` too. It not worked.

Comment: What should i fill in device section.?? >Hannu

Comment: I see that you found out. As you did not have file system type nor other info in your initial question, I could not help you there.

Comment: Next time i will keep that in my mind while asking question. But, thanks for helping. Peace.